# Rewriting old URLs to new, clean ones

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have me .htaccess file happily rewriting things like `/conferences/details/21` to `/index.php?pages=conferences&var1=details&var2=21`.

I have Piwik tracking this site, which is showing up a lot of referrals from sites that haven't update their URLs (it's a very new site re-do) with URLs such as

```
http://www.domain.com/index.cfm?page=conference&intConferenceID=81
```

And

```
http://www.domain.com/index.cfm?page=conference&intConferenceID=88&type=conference
```

I'd like to rewrite them to `/conferences/details/[numeric ID seen above]`.

I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.cfm?page=conference&intConferenceID=(\d+)/?$ /conferences/details/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Obvisouly ignoring the second example. However, it gives me a 404 saying `index.cfm` can't be found.

What rewrite rule do I need to write to rewrite the above formatted links (the IDs change) to `/conferences/details/[ID]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the query string from RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.cfm
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.+)&intConferenceID=([^&]+)
RewriteRule . /%1/details/%2 [L]
```

Not sure where the "details" comes from based on the `/foo/bar/21` -> `/index.php?f=foo&b=bar&arg=21` rewriting.

Comment: Thanks very much. The `details` comes from the clean URL, which is like this: `/conferences/details/21`. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Basically, the RewriteRule won't rewrite the query string, just the path. You need to use a RewriteCond to match the query string and access those matches with a %